# CPU usage 100% while using Geoserver with zoom level 2 or 3

Tags: sql-server, gis, cpu-usage, geoserver

I am using Geoserver as a map server having around 30000 data in it. Geoserver consuming 100% CPU when I zoom out the tile to 2 or 3 zoom level and when I zoom in to 17 or 18 it still consumes 15 to 20% CPU usage for single user. I am using SQL server with geoserver on same system.

How to overcome with this problem I have read many posts related to this problem but did not found any solution yet.

Comment: I think more details are needed. Can you say more about what kind of layer you're showing (feature type, count, density, complexity, etc), and the role of SQL Server in this scenario? How long does the CPU spike last for?

Comment: we are using sql server to serve geospatial data and it renders at the frontend through the geoserver. and it spikes in 2 to 3 sec for a single user.

Comment: 3000 what? do you have any scale dependent styling or does GeoServer have to draw your entire dataset when you zoom out to 2-3.

Comment: sorry actually there is 30000 rows with geospatial data and the attribute. Here geoserver gets the data using microsoft SQL server store and openlayers and leaflet application consumes the wms service.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your JRE/JDK version. I had the same problem and installing/upgrading JRE version resolved the issue for me.